# How can OSMdroid and OSMBonusPack use OpenStreetMap's Barrier?

Tags: android, dictionary, gps, routes, openstreetmap

I am currently working in Android Studio on a GPS app that will route me from my current location to a set destination.
Beforehand, along this road I want to make some of the streets and routes **unusable** forcing the GPS to guide me the shortest distance NOT using these **unusable** routes.

For example, I am driving from A towards B. In between the shortest normal route takes me over a bridge. This bridge has collapsed and is being marked with a MapOverlayItem in the shape of a big red cross. I want the GPS to know the bridge is out and guide me to an alternative route.

I am using OSMdroid for map and OSMBonusPack for routing.
I know that OSM have exactly what I [need](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:barrier) but I am not sure on how to use them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine solved it.

```
@Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(GeoPoint... geoPoints) {
        String url = getRoadUrl(geoPoints[0]);
        HttpConnection connection = new HttpConnection();
        connection.doGet(url);
        String s = connection.getContentAsString();
        String[] split = s.split("\"linkId\":");
        split = split[1].split(",");

        return Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
    }
```

By finding the route's ID you can explicitly ask it not to calculate by that road. The above code is just a snippet to show how we ask a road not to be used. Ask if you need a more describing version of this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible, unfortunately. As far as I can see, *OSMBonusPack* doesn't do the routing itself (offline routing) but uses MapQuest instead (online routing). Consequently you can't add arbitrary barriers yourself. The only solution is to use an [offline router](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/offline_routers) for [android](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android#Navigating_features).